# Validate enhanced Rich Text Field on PreSaveAction call on newform in SP 2010 List Form

Tags: javascript, list-form, newform

How to validate `Enhanced Rich Text Field` on `PreSaveAction` call in my SP 2010 list form's `newform.aspx`.
I tried with JavaScript but it didn't work.

I followed Marc's blog  [here](http://sympmarc.com/2011/02/10/finding-the-contents-of-a-sharepoint-rich-text-column-with-jquery/)

But the issue is, once it's validated successfully, I delete the  text contents again and re-enter the text contents again and tried to validate and it failed!
Also the field needs to be mandatory field.

Comment: How did you retrieve the rich text content in PreSaveAction?

Comment: $("textarea[Title='Detailed Status']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']").blur(function(){

  alert($(this).contents().find("body").html());

});

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code

```
$("td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr:contains('Field Name')").parent().parent().parent().find("div.ms-inputBox div.ms-rtestate-write").text()
```

Replace the 'Field Name' token with column display name

Comment: Let me try and revert.thanks for your time -@ Nagarajan.

Comment: the above didn't work for me, when I edit the form,though the old status text  values been mentioned already and it didn't fetch the latest value, it seems.When I tried to alert the status value am not getting any value. but its not null text.

Comment: var detailedStatusTxtValue =  $("td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr:contains('detailed Status')").parent().parent().parent().find("div.ms-inputBox div.ms-rtestate-write").text();

alert(detailedStatusTxtValue + '  is the current detailed status value ');

if(detailedStatusTxtValue == null )
{
alert('detailedStatusTxtValue Value is mandatory!');
return false;
}
else
{
alert('detailedStatusTxtValue is not null');
//return true;
}  and as the result,  i got the message   "is the current detailed status" value "

Comment: instead of entering in the if loop, it enters inside the not null block and get the result as ---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
detailedStatusTxtValue is not null
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: instead of detailedStatusTxtValue == null use detailedStatusTxtValue == "" and check it.

Comment: You saved my day...Thanks i know this solution is a bit messy but that's the way to go... cheers..